# MySQL SELECT DISTINCT multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

Let's say I have columns `a, b c, d` in a table in a MySQL database. What I'm trying to do is to select the distinct values of ALL of these 4 columns in my table (only the distinct values). I tried stuff like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c,d FROM my_table;
SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c,d FROM my_table GROUP BY a,b,c,d;
```

None of those worked. Can anybody help out here?

Thank you

**NOTE** I want the distinct values of the columns `a, b, c d` separately. Not the distinct combination of values

Comment: if it has any unique column, this will not work. distinct does not work on unique column.

Comment: None of the columns are unique

Comment: then you are getting the correct result as long as you are not using join

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter Of course it would work - why would distinct not work on a unique column,

Comment: You should explain what you mean by "distinct values of ALL of these 4 columns", as it must mean something different to you than it usually means for those queries to not return what you want. Sample data and sample output would be a concise way of conveying that.

Comment: Do you want all the distinct a's b's, c's and d's or the distinct combination of the values - your 1st query should work

Comment: I want distinct values of a's, b's c's and d's, not combination of values

Answer (score 62, accepted):

can this help?

```
select 
(SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT a) FROM my_table) as a,
(SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT b) FROM my_table) as b,
(SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT c) FROM my_table) as c,
(SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT d) FROM my_table) as d
```

Comment: What if I need only distinct results from first two column but need to show all columns...

Comment: ncastro's is better. Cooler, easier, anyway.

Comment: Hey Nesim, Thanks! by the way if "my_table" is a whole query how can I call it by name and recall it again and again

Comment: But this result gives comma separated value. How can I get rid of this problems.

Comment: Chayan, that's a different issues, but it's `REPLACE(group_concat(DISTINCT d),',',' ')`

Comment: Mysql Error as :
                      #1247 - Reference 'a' not supported (forward reference in item list).

Comment: Note that this will silently truncate each resulting column to `group_concat_max_len` characters long, [which by default](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) is only 1024 characters - you could lose data!

Comment: distinct results from first tow rows `SELECT
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a FROM my_table LIMIT 2) AS a)  AS a,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT b FROM my_table LIMIT 2) AS b)  AS b;`

Comment: group_contact is a mysql function. Is there any agnostic server function to replace that? I need this query to be translated to JPA.

Answer (score 120):

I know that the question is too old, anyway:

```
SELECT a, b
FROM mytable
GROUP BY a, b;
```

This will give your all the combinations.

Comment: Kinda cool. The 'group by' forces the distinct-ness. Is that what is happening?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more the query?

Comment: @ncastro Apologies, but this answer does not satisfy the question.

Comment: This one is slow for large tables.

Comment: Came here for that. I have a query that takes nearly a second, and without the grouping it takes 3ms.

Answer (score 28):

Another simple way to do it is with `concat()`

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT(a,b)) AS cc FROM my_table GROUP BY (cc);
```

Comment: Sorry, But I cannot find any equivalent in Derby Database.

Comment: This is clever and it's exactly what I needed

Comment: This is what worked for me. I didn't know how to use the other answers with the multiple joins I have in the query

Comment: Very slow for large tables.

Comment: This one is really clever.

Answer (score 22):

Taking a guess at the results you want so maybe this is the query you want then

```
SELECT DISTINCT a FROM my_table
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT b FROM my_table
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT c FROM my_table
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT d FROM my_table
```

Comment: This works too, but I like the separation between the results better in Nesim Razon's answer. Thank you

Comment: Cool - I was going to look at combining them

Comment: If you want DISTINCT values across all the columns, you have to wrap this query in another SELECT statement like this: `SELECT DISTINCT value
FROM (
 SELECT DISTINCT a AS value FROM my_table
 UNION SELECT DISTINCT b AS value FROM my_table
 UNION SELECT DISTINCT c AS value FROM my_table
) AS derived`

Comment: `SELECT e,f FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT zdjh AS e FROM `tj_xhqd`
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT sjsj AS f FROM `tj_xhqd`
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT xhqd AS g FROM `tj_xhqd`) a`

gives me `Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'f' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 11):

This will give DISTINCT values across all the columns:

```
SELECT DISTINCT value
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT a AS value FROM my_table
    UNION SELECT DISTINCT b AS value FROM my_table
    UNION SELECT DISTINCT c AS value FROM my_table
) AS derived
```

Comment: Nice example that solved my problem easily.  Thanks.

Comment: It will give me the values in the single column what if I want to show them separately ?

Answer (score 9):

Both your queries are correct and should give you the right answer.

I would suggest the following query to troubleshoot your problem.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c,d,count(*) Count FROM my_table GROUP BY a,b,c,d
order by count(*) desc
```

That is add count(*) field. This will give you idea how many rows were eliminated using the group command.

Comment: I want disctinct values of a's, b's, c's and d's, not distinct combination of values

Comment: @hmd: Thanks for this solution. Exactly what I needed. Is there is way to include a `where` condition? I wanted only rows where the count was greater than 1. Tried `select distinct a,b,c,count(*) from MyTempTable group by a,b,c order by count(*) desc where count(*)>1;` but it didn't work.

Comment: @Nav42 you need to use `having count(*) > 1` not `where` as this is aggregate query. Btw my answer does not exactly addresses the OP question as he is outlined above. Anyways glad to help.

Comment: Works. Thank you very much. select `distinct a,b,c,count(*) from MyTable group by a,b,c having count(*) > 1 order by count(*) desc `

Answer (score 5):

`select distinct concat( colA , ' ' , colB , ' ' , colC ) from tableName;`

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32586107)

Comment: It doesn't warrant more explanation, it's self-explanatory. Delete the answer if you don't like it, I added it because none of the other answers was that simple

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this to get back one row with four comma separated lists with all values.

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `a`) AS `as`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `b`) AS `bs`,                
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `c`) AS `cs`,                
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `d`) AS `ds`
FROM
  `my_table`;
```

If you need an other separator than the comma, add the `SEPARATOR` option to `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answers I made the same but for extracting a json column `vars` with arrays of 8 values all merged in 1 column with quotes trimed distinct values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM T1.`vars`) FROM (
    SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`vars`, '$[1]') AS `vars` 
         FROM my_table
         WHERE `vars` != '[]'
         UNION 
    SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`vars`, '$[2]') AS `vars`
         FROM my_table
         WHERE `vars` != '[]'
         UNION 
    SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`vars`, '$[3]') AS `vars`
         FROM my_table
         WHERE `vars` != '[]'
         UNION 
    SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`vars`, '$[4]') AS `vars`
         FROM my_table
         WHERE `vars` != '[]'
         UNION 
    SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`vars`, '$[5]') AS `vars`
         FROM my_table
         WHERE `vars` != '[]'
         UNION 
    SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`vars`, '$[6]') AS `vars`
         FROM my_table
         WHERE `vars` != '[]'
         UNION 
    SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`vars`, '$[7]') AS `vars`
         FROM my_table
         WHERE `vars` != '[]'
         UNION 
    SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`vars`, '$[8]') AS `vars`
         FROM my_table
         WHERE `vars` != '[]'
) T1
WHERE `vars` IS NOT NULL
AND `vars` != 'false';
```

Hope it can helps...

Answer (score 0):

i do NOT know the values of your columns are ids as mine, so here is my solution if it fits you

```
SELECT DISTINCT (sender+receiver) AS smart_sum, sender, receiver 
FROM chatTable 
WHERE sender=1 OR receiver=1 
GROUP BY smart_sum
```

I have a chat table, sender and receiver columns represent the user_id of each, so the sum of them is actually unique.