# MYSQL Distinct for two column

Tags: php, mysql, distinct, concatenation

I got two columns: sender, receiver in my table. I want to get the distinct for both column where sender or receiver equal to b and then concat them into string.

```
....................
sender  |  receiver
....................
  a            b
  c            b
  b            a
  b            c
  d            f
  b            e
  b            e
  e            b
```

The result set should look like a,b,c,e

What should I do to achieve this?

Comment: If you concat them , you have two letters, so the result `a,b,c,e` would be two pairs. The second pair doesn't contain `b`, so I'm curious how you get that result...

Comment: Also, this can probably be done in SQL. Are you looking for a MySQL solution? If so, please remove the PHP tag, since it would be irrelevant for the query itself.

Comment: To put a closure to your question, please mark any one of the answers as accepted if they helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do 2 unioned queries to get the values. Union should eliminate the duplicates. Then you can use that as a sub query and do a GROUP_CONCAT on the results:-

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(aCol)
FROM
(
    SELECT sender AS aCol
    FROM SomeTable
    WHERE sender = 'b'
    OR receiver = 'b'
    UNION
    SELECT receiver AS aCol
    FROM SomeTable
    WHERE sender = 'b'
    OR receiver = 'b'
) sub0
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this thread : [MySQL SELECT DISTINCT multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188027/mysql-select-distinct-multiple-columns)

```
SELECT DISTINCT value FROM
( 
    SELECT DISTINCT a AS value FROM my_table
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT b AS value FROM my_table
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT c AS value FROM my_table 
) AS derived
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
create table test (sender char(1), receiver char(1));    
insert into test values ('a','b'), ('c','b'), ('b','a'), ('b','c'), ('d','f'), ('b','e'), ('b', 'e'), ('e', 'b');

select group_concat(sender  separator ',') as result 
from (
  select sender from test where receiver = 'b' 
  union
  select 'b'
) alias;

+---------+
| result  |
+---------+
| a,c,e,b |
+---------+
```

If you want alphabetical ordering, you can replace `select 'b'` with `select 'b' order by sender` and you will get `a,b,c,e` as the result