# want a unique values from all column from a given table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table named as test like

```
+------+------+-------+-------+
| id   | date | xname | yname |
+------+------+-------+-------+
| 1001 | 2015 | A     | A     |
| 1001 | 2014 | B     | Y     |
| 1002 | 2016 | A     | A     |
| 1001 | 2016 | B     | Y     |
| 1002 | 2014 | A     | A     |
+------+------+-------+-------+
```

And i want unique values from each column like

```
+------+------+-------+-------+
| id   | date | xname | yname |
+------+------+-------+-------+
| 1001 | 2014 | B     | Y     |
| 1002 | 2016 | A     | A     |
+------+------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Please edit the question and show the results that you want.

Comment: We need to know **what unique value** you want, so please do as Gordon suggests or nobody will bother answering this question as it is only possible to guess at what you want. Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL SELECT DISTINCT multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188027/mysql-select-distinct-multiple-columns)

Comment: The DISTINCT keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT '1001' id
     , '2014' date
     , 'B' xname
     , 'Y' yname
 UNION 
SELECT '1002' 
     , '2016'
     , 'A'
     , 'A';
```