# How to use DISTINCT keyword for more than one column in single mysql query?

Tags: mysql, distinct

I tried the below query but it not works.

```
Select DISTINCT firstname,lastname from users;
```

I need the `DISTINCT` records of `first` and `last name`.

This is the records:

```
first name | lastname | language_known
sakthi     | vel      | English
hari       | Prasath  | Chinese
Varun      | Kumar    | English
```

I need the above three results but need to remove the duplication of English which come two times in the result

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? Can you give example with data, result and your expected result?

Comment: `select distinct a,b,c from ... ` means distinct for the whole lot

Comment: you can used group by clause 
`SELECT  firstname,lastname FROM users GROUP BY   firstname,lastname`

Comment: You need to do a group by firstname, lastname, in some subquery/derived table and pontificate how you want to deal with TieBreaks: ie, which one to choose ... because you are going to lose data with this concept but that is what you seem to want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL SELECT DISTINCT multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188027/mysql-select-distinct-multiple-columns)

Comment: How do you want to remove duplication of English, and still keep three results? What result do you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DISTINCT firstname,lastname from users;
```

called on this data you have presented will first of all select first name and last name from the table, resulting in:

```
firstname | lastname 
sakthi    | vel      
hari      | Prasath  
Varun     | Kumar
```

And then will remove the duplicate rows, however there are no duplicates in this result set, so it will be returned as is:

```
firstname | lastname 
sakthi    | vel      
hari      | Prasath  
Varun     | Kumar
```

What result do you want to get?