# Active Record (MYSQL) - Select distinct ids from multiple columns

Tags: mysql, activerecord

`Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73`

`activerecord (4.1.14)`

I have a trade model that belongs to a lender and borrower. I want to find all uniq counterparties to an institution's trades in one SQL query. The query below works, but only because I flatten & unique-ify the array after the SQL query:

```
Trade.where("borrower_id = :id OR lender_id = :id", id: institution.id).uniq.pluck(:lender_id, :borrower_id).flatten.uniq
```

(I know this includes the institution itself, so we normalize after with `[1,2,3,4] - [1]`)

But what I'd like to do is use a `Group By` clause or something so that my SQL query handles the `flatten.uniq` part.

The below does not work because it returns a nested array of unique *combinations* of `lender_id` and `borrower_id`:

```
Trade.where("borrower_id = :id OR lender_id = :id", id: institution.id).group(:lender_id, :borrower_id).uniq.pluck(:lender_id, :borrower_id)

=> [[1,2], [1,3], [2,3]]
```

I want a flat array of JUST unique ids: `[1,2,3]`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're trying to, or why you'd want to include a GROUP BY clause in the absence of any aggregating functions.

FWIW, a valid query might look like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.lender_id
              , t.borrower_id
           FROM trades t
          WHERE 28 IN(t.borrower_id,t.lender_id);
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I was using a GROUP BY because of similar SO posts (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188027/mysql-select-distinct-multiple-columns?rq=1).... I'm open to whatever works! That being said, your query results in a nested array return set that includes unique _combinations_ of lender_id and borrower_id (e.g. [ [1, 2], [1, 3] ])... I need just the unique ids as a flat array (e.g [ 1,2,3 ]).

Comment: i would do that kind of processing in the app.

Comment: LOL, that's what I'm doing (`flatten.uniq`), but I want to learn how I can do this via SQL / ActiveRecord (hence the question). Seems like a pretty relevant / frequent use case.

Comment: Well in that case, lose the DISTINCT and instead include a GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT...) function (and that GROUP BY clause again) - but I think your existing method (or something like it) is better.