# Select distinct on multiple columns with where statement

Tags: php, mysql, select, doctrine, distinct

I want to select each available entry for each column once. This problem was solved with

```
SELECT DISTINCT a from my_table
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT b from my_table
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT c from my_table
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT d from my_table
```

in this question: [MySQL SELECT DISTINCT multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188027/mysql-select-distinct-multiple-columns)

I want to go further and use **the same** `WHERE` statements on each subquery. Is there any way without defining the `WHERE` each time? My current query would look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a from my_table WHERE a='a' AND b=1 AND c='.' AND d='ab'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT b from my_table WHERE a='a' AND b=1 AND c='.' AND d='ab'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT c from my_table WHERE a='a' AND b=1 AND c='.' AND d='ab'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT d from my_table WHERE a='a' AND b=1 AND c='.' AND d='ab'
```

All parameters don't have to be given, I just want to show the maximum that has to be possible. Is there any way to write this shorter?

I use PHP with doctrine, if that is any help.

Thanks in advance!

Example:
my_table:

```
  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  
-----+-----+-----+-----
  a  |  0  |  .  | ab
  b  |  0  |  -  | ag
  a  |  1  |  .  | cfd
  c  |  1  |  .  | b
  a  |  1  |  -  | ab
  c  |  1  |  -  | cfd
```

should give this result (without where statement):

```
  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  
-----+-----+-----+-----
  a  |  0  |  .  | ab
  b  |  1  |  -  | ag
  c  |     |     | cfd
     |     |     |  b
```

And with `WHERE b=0` statement:

```
  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  
-----+-----+-----+-----
  a  |  0  |  .  | ab
  b  |     |  -  | ag
```

EDIT: changed subqueries to UNION and made the data types fit to the example

Comment: how you `WHERE` say `a = 1` when `a` is a text field?

Comment: The query from the original post uses `GROUP_CONCAT` whereas the query you cite doesn't Your query won't execute if any of the subqueries returns more than one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Well, I originally wrote up a generic SQL solution for this problem, not realizing that MySQL apparently doesn't allow for it.

So if you can create a view, that may be the lightest-weight solution.  (The view's defining query would be the same as the `select` in my original solution's `with` clause.)

Alternately you could create a temporary table.  Maybe a little more resource-intensive if there's much data, but less likely that anyone would restrict the required permissions.

For the record, original solution was as follows:

```
with my_filtered as (
    select *
      from my_table
     where a = 1 and b = 2 -- and ...
)
-- carry on with your query, using my_filtered instead of my_table
```

Comment: MySql doesnt have `WITH`

Comment: Its working the same with temporary tables under mysql