# Group by on multiple columns with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following database.

```
msg
....
 - uid (pk)
 - sender
 - msg

relation
---------
 - uid (fk)
 - reciever
```

A message can go to several recipients and I want to receive a unique list of all recipients and senders. The problem is that a sender can also be a reciever so I get duplicates.

An example is :

```
SELECT  msg.sender,relation.reciever,msg.msg,msg.uid from msg inner join relation on msg.uid = relation.uid group by msg.sender;


+-------------+-------------+-------+-----+
| sender      | reciever    | msg   | uid |
+-------------+-------------+-------+-----+
| 123         | 321         | Test1 | 1   |
| 321         | 123         | Test2 | 2   |
+-------------+-------------+-------+-----+
```

The problem is that now, duplicates exist. I want one of them, not both where sender or reciever is unique in either field. To accomplish this I added msg.reciever in the group by like this :

```
SELECT  msg.sender,relation.number,msg.msg,msg.uid from msg inner join
 relation on msg.uid = relation.uid group by msg.sender, relations.reciever;
```

But the result is the same. How would I accomplish the task of producing unique results across two columns?

For clarification the final result should be:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------+-----+
| sender      | reciever    | msg   | uid |
+-------------+-------------+-------+-----+
| 123         | 321         | Test1 | 1   |
+-------------+-------------+-------+-----+
```

or

```
+-------------+-------------+-------+-----+
| sender      | reciever    | msg   | uid |
+-------------+-------------+-------+-----+
| 321         | 123         | Test2 | 2   |
+-------------+-------------+-------+-----+
```

Comment: I think this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188027/mysql-select-distinct-multiple-columns

Comment: Sorry if I'm not on the same page here, but I would want the distinct combination of values? As in the opposite of what he is asking?

Answer (score 0):

Use a union to create a single column on which to apply the group by.

Something like this:

```
select * from 
(
      SELECT  msg.sender as user, msg.msg,msg.uid from msg 
      inner join relation on msg.uid = relation.uid
   union
      SELECT  relation.reciever as user, msg.msg,msg.uid from msg 
      inner join relation on msg.uid = relation.uid
) Temp
group by user
```